# Schema.org Accommodation with price?

Tags: schema.org, json-ld

I'm attempting to add a schema for an [`Accommodation`](https://schema.org/Accommodation), but I can't seem to find a way to reference the 'offer' or 'price' to this schema. Im using JSON-LD to format this schema.

I have also tried room/hotelRoom as an alternative.  I also tried using the `additionalType` value to allow me to use product based options such as `offers`, but this didn't work.

JSON-LD:

```json
{
   "@context": "http://schema.org",
        "@type": "Accommodation",
        "additionalType": "Product",
        "name": "example",
        "offers": {
            "@type": "Offer",
            "name": "1 Night",
            "priceSpecification": {
                "@type": "PriceSpecification",
                "price": 1,
                "minPrice": 1,
                "maxPrice": 2,
                "priceCurrency": "GBP"
            }
        }
}
```

**Google Structured Data Testing Tool:**

> The property `offers` is not recognized by Google for an object of type `Accommodation`.

How am I meant to add a price to a specific accommodation/room in my schema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Schema.org intends¹ that authors use MTEs² in this case. That, however, does of course not necessarily mean that all consumers fully support this (yet).

So instead of:

```json
"@type": "Accommodation",
```

you would use:

```json
"@type": ["Accommodation", "Product"],
```

(`additionalType": "Product",` is not needed anymore, so could be removed)

While Google’s Structured Data Testing Tool only displays one type (seems to be always the first value in the array), it reports no errors when using this.

---

¹ The [accommodation documentation](http://schema.org/docs/hotels.html) does not yet reflect this (the changes are currently part of the [draft for the next version](http://pending.webschemas.org/docs/hotels.html)), and the topic gets discussed here:

- [Remove Accommodation from all of the Offer-related schema and use MTEs instead](https://github.com/schemaorg/schemaorg/issues/1264)
- [Hotel examples and documentation must be updated for MTE pattern](https://github.com/schemaorg/schemaorg/issues/1320)

² MTE: Multi-Typed Entity.